# Homework - Getting DateTime in custom format in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I select a value from a `DateTime` column in the `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS` (HH is 24-hour) format?

P.S.: The return vale of the SELECT query can be any datatype.

Comment: it's all here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: SO is not a place for people to do your homework

Comment: @Oded: In the page that gbn has linked, I noticed that the format that I specifically want isn't listed. So I wanted someone to show me a simple method of getting it that way, from where I can figure out other custom formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME
SET @dt = GETDATE()
PRINT CONVERT(varchar, @dt, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @dt, 108)
```

In a select statement it would look like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, yourDateField, 103) + ' ' +
       CONVERT(varchar, yourDateField, 108) as YourFieldName, ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as this is homework, just some tips:

You need to read up on the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) Sql function. Then, you need to realise that your requirement is a mix of two different formats (one for the date; hint - Italian) and one for the time part. Simply `Convert` your date into the two formats and concatentate them with a space in between

Your code will end up looking like the following:

```
select 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), your_date, date_format ) + ' ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), your_date,time_format ) 
from ...
```